# How to import modules in plain Typescript environment

Tags: typescript, ecmascript-6

I want to use pure Typescript for a small app without using frameworks like Vue.js or React and also without bundle managers like Web-pack. Because the setup code would be bigger than my app and it would be so much bloatware.

But when I try to run on a local server there is an error saying:

```
ReferenceError: Cannot find variable: MainClass 
Module Core - index.html:8
```

I have my project folder set up in this way:

```
/src
    MainClass.ts
    MainClass.js*
    SubClass.ts
    SubClass.js*
index.html
tsconfig.json
```

<sup>*: *Automatically compiled by tsconfig.json*</sup>

## Index.html

```
<html>
<body>
    <script type="module" src="./src/MainClass.js"></script>
    <script type="module">
        var mainClass = new MainClass()
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

## tsconfig.json

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "module": "ES6",
        "target": "ES6"
    },
    "include": ["src/**/*"]
}
```

## MainClass.ts

```
import { SubClass } from "./SubClass"   

export default class Main {
    private subClass: SubClass

    constructor() {
        this.subClass = new SubClass()
    }
}
```

## SubClass.ts (class imported in main)

```
export class SubClass {
    constructor() { }
}
```

Comment: You probably have to import `MainClass` in the body of the inline script like `import MainClass from "./src/MainClass.js"`, then you don't need the first script tag for `MainClass.js`

Comment: Thanks @artem that was it.